# Summing values in multiple CSVs python

Tags: python, csv

I have multiple CSVs, Output A, OutputB, OutputC, OutputD and Output Other in this format:

OutputA:

```
Cat,Name,Club,Points
A,James,1,100
A,Mark,1,99
A,Tom,2,98
```

OutputB:

```
Cat,Name,Club,Points
B,James,2,95
B,Mark,1,94
B,Tom,2,93
```

output C and D follow the same format however outputother is as follows:

```
Reason,Name,Club,Points
LJ,James,2,1
PP,George,1,1
```

Effecitvely the main difference is points are always 1.

I want to create a new CSV which has the rows club, total points, average points per person, and the number of people in each club so the output CSV from the examples above would be:

```
Club,Total,Avg,Numberofpeople
1,294,73.5,4
2,287,71.75,4
```

I know how to open the CSV get the values, and write to a new CSV but I do not know how to do conditional sums with python or how to sum rows from a CSV. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Comment: @wwii I believe this question is fair, I need some help in doing conditional with Python. There is nothing in the Python tutorial about this, or has a question been asked about this on SO before. I have done my research but have not found suitable support.

Comment: For each file; as you read each row make a [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html); and put it in a list; after reading all the files [sort](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) the list by club and person; [group by](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) club; for each group; count number of ppl, nbr of unique ppl, accumulate total score.